# Mudblazor displays value @bind-Value not as expected

Tags: autocomplete, blazor, mudblazor

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdYsC.png)

How to display @bind-value like this: design-value

The code like this:

Product.cs

```cs
namespace Shared.Domains
{
  public class Product
  {
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Design { get; set; }
  }
}
```

ProductsController.cs (Web Api)

```cs
[HttpGet("get")]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<Product>>> Get()
{
  return await _context.Products.ToListAsync();
}
```

ProductDetails.razor (code)

```cs
  private Product design;

  private async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> Design(string value)
  {
    var data = await HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Product>>("/products/get");
    data = data.Select(x => new Product
                            {
                              Design = x.Design
                            }).ToList();

    // if text is null or empty, show complete list
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) 
      return data;

    return data.Where(x => x.Design.Contains(value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
  }
```

ProductDetails.razor (razor)

```cs
          <MudAutocomplete T="Product" Label="Design" ResetValueOnEmptyText="true"
              @bind-Value="@design" SearchFunc="@Design" MaxItems="null"
              ToStringFunc="@(e=> e == null ? null : e.Design)" />
          @(design?.ToString() ?? "Not selected")
```

Output that I have is **Shared.Domains.Product**

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved.

should type like this!

```
@(design != null ? design.Design : "Not selected")
```